# Compute the visible length of a notification in the WP8.1 action center

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

as you can see below (screenshot from [windowsphone.com](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/windows/windows-10-mobile-upgrade?rtc=1)), a notification in the notification center of WP8.1 can only be **one line** long (potentially with an additional "title" line - see Mail to "Maurice" here under).

[image: Notification Center]
<sub>(source: [windowsphone.com](https://assets.windowsphone.com/307b9d9e-8a75-4ef5-a549-dcd2890f7891/action-center-full-callout_InvariantCulture_Default.png))</sub>

My app sends notifications to the action center, and I would like to pre-compute the length of the notification i.e. know if it fits in the screen or not.

In case of a standard text, I can use [an invisible text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848815/wp8-xaml-measure-string-length-in-pixels) to compute the length of the rendered text. But in this case, the problem is that the text is not part of **MY** UI, but part of the action center... and I have no idea which style is used and if some ease-of-use presets (UI zooming) are set.

Any idea how I could approach this problem?

*Edit as discussed in the comments:*

1. I tried an "averageing" approach by estimating the font size and the average size of a sentence. Unfortunately, the string is not long enough that the dispersion flattens out, "iii" is way shorter than "mmm" and fixing the length at say - 32 chars - will produce too unreliable results.
2. The ease of access zoom factor is a dealbreaker here since it can cut the length of the displayed text in up to a half.

Comment: What do you want exactly by measuring this length? Actually it is not possible but i asked to find you some another way.

Comment: My app allows the users to display a given text in the notification center. I would like to give them a visual hint once the text they are typing will not appear on the screen anymore.

Comment: it displays average 30 characters. So you can measure this something like this. (Your screen width - (character size * 30)). System font size are fixed so you can measure font width. Let me know if this gives you some hint.

Comment: That's pretty much what I tried, but the results are too unreliable. 1) Just compare the length of "iii" and "mmm" to see what I mean ;) 2) The ease-of-access settings can cut the number of visible characters in half...

Comment: In this case you can use average width of the fonts. These all, I am telling based on custom logic because there is no direct methods to achieve this.